# The system cannot find the path specified when using MicrocontrollerEmbedCode

Tags: microcontroller-kit

I am trying to work with [`MicrocontrollerEmbedCode`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/MicrocontrollerKit/ref/MicrocontrollerEmbedCode.html), but no luck so far.
The code was not uploaded to the Arduino and  I got this message: 
"The system cannot find the path specified".

Note:
The Arduino IDE is working fine and I can upload codes to the Arduino.

How to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are on Windows. The connection port should be some COMx. You can find the specific one the Arduino is connected to using DeviceManager > Ports.

Comment: Yes, it works. as simple as that. Thanks